# Which IP used to connect Virtualbox CentOs with Windows

Tags: centos, windows, virtualbox, ip

I'm using Virtualbox to run CentOs and I'd like to know which is the IP used to connect my VM (CentOs) with my local machine (Windows).

When I run `ifconfig` on CentOs, got this results:

```
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::5048:63:3271:b7d4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:46:b8:4f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 214900  bytes 249355246 (237.8 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 29228  bytes 1764854 (1.6 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 655  bytes 167014 (163.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 655  bytes 167014 (163.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:53:37:45  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

How do I know which of the 3 IP's (`10.0.2.15`, `127.0.0.1` or `192.168.122.1`) is connecting my virtual machine CentOs with my local machine (Windows)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't 127.0.0.1 - that's the loopback address. It's either enp0s3 or virbr0.

virbr0 is used by virtual machines to connect to outside environments, according to this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/246343/what-is-the-virbr0-interface-used-for

I would expect virbr0 to be used for a Linux host to connect to a guest.

I think this rules out loopback and virbr0. I'm guessing the answer is enp0s3.

You can probably test this using `ip route get <some external address>`

Comment: 10.0.2.2 is the IP address of the host and 10.0.2.15 is the VM with Virtualbox's default setting of "NAT" and emulated hardware.

Comment: I don't see 10.0.2.2

Comment: @bat check it via `ip route`

Comment: How can I test it @bat?

Comment: I like the `ip route` idea. Perhaps you could get an IP using ping, say `ping www.google.com` and then use it as follows: `ip route get to 172.217.7.132`

Comment: @HenriqueBranco see my edit in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your guest OS network settings. It looks like that it uses 10.0.2.15 to communicate with your host machine using NAT mode (identifiable via IP 10.0.2.15/24 as it's the default network of NAT mode). Unless your host machine is connected to (real) 10.0.2.0/24 network, then it might be Bridged mode attached to your main network interface.

I assume that you wanted to do nested virtualization. As it's the default bridge interface for KVM and also the IP (192.168.122.1/24) is the default for it. Therefore, you got `virbr0` there.

Conclusion, it uses 10.0.2.15 to communicate with your Windows machine. See table below to understand better:

```
+------------+---------+--------------+---------+------------+--------------+
| Mode       | VM→Host | VM←Host      | VM1↔VM2 | VM→Net/LAN | VM←Net/LAN   |
+------------+---------+--------------+---------+------------+--------------+
| Host-only  | +       | +            | +       | –          | –            |
+------------+---------+--------------+---------+------------+--------------+
| Internal   | –       | –            | +       | –          | –            |
+------------+---------+--------------+---------+------------+--------------+
| Bridged    | +       | +            | +       | +          | +            |
+------------+---------+--------------+---------+------------+--------------+
| NAT        | +       | Port forward | –       | +          | Port forward |
+------------+---------+--------------+---------+------------+--------------+
| NATservice | +       | Port forward | +       | +          | Port forward |
+------------+---------+--------------+---------+------------+--------------+
```

More details about Virtualbox networking: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

Answer (score 1):

So I had a similar question a few weeks ago. And I did make this account to respond, as my error was very enlightening to me.

Your VM has its own network and you can either have a NAT, or bridged network. So when you run ifconfig, and you see vibr0, the IP Address given is actually the gateway address for your VMs network interface. If this was a bare-metal install you would not see a vibr0 as there is no virtual machine supporting this OS.

If your VM was NAT(i remember this as network attached but that is not what the acronym means), it would have a branch from the VM gateway, so your IP address would look more like 192.168.122.X. to use the link Annahri posted, under 6.3 NAT:

> A virtual machine with NAT enabled acts much like a real computer that connects to the Internet through a router. The router, in this case, is the Oracle VM VirtualBox networking engine, which maps traffic from and to the virtual machine transparently. In Oracle VM VirtualBox this router is placed between each virtual machine and the host.

If NAT was enabled he would be going through the VM "router" which is vibr0, which has a different gateway address.

It looks to me like it is bridged. What this means is you have bridged the network from your vm to your host network. I guarantee you if you open up command prompt in windows, and run ipconfig, your ip address for your host machine is similiar to 10.0.0.X. When you run ipconfig from command prompt it also gives you the gateway address which should be 10.0.0.1.

I had similar IP address as yours and when i changed my VM from NAT to bridged it went from a 192 IP to 10 on reboot.

Another point just from my experience, any IP address that ends in .1 is a gateway address. So your question digs heavily into networking, and if you dont know much, it will force you to learn. 
Your VM should allow you to choose between the two(NAT or BRIDGED) during setup and allow you to change from one to the other even after set up, in VM preferences. keep in mind you will get a new IP address if you change it from one to the other, but should keep your old IP address if you change back.

Annahri posted a link that is a bit more of a deeper dive into it, as there are more options than just NAT or bridged.

Comment: From my experience, if you set a vm to use NAT mode, its IP would be assigned to 10.0.2.0/24 network as default, in most cases  10.0.2.15. And 192.168.122.0/24 is the default for the Host-only network.

Comment: Is there a way on here that you and I can chat about this, I just made a vm this morning and bridged the network and it has the same gateway and IP branch as my host. I checked my old VM that was defaulted to NAT and never changed and it has the vibr0 gateway.

Comment: I just booted to my old vm (CentOS), and I verified the network settings which is single interface with NAT mode. And guess what, I got 10.0.2.15/24. I strongly believe that you set it with 2 interfaces, NAT and Bridged, hence you got extra interface called virbr0 on your vm.